# Magento 2: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId()

Tags: magento2, module, admin, custom

After adding custom module on Server. It's giving below error

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null
 in
 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Menu.php:296
 Stack trace: #0
 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(975):
 Magento\Backend\Block\Menu->getCacheKeyInfo() #1
 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(1027):
 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getCacheKey() #2
 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(652):
 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() #3
 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542):
 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() #4
 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('menu') #5
 /var/www/html/magento/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206):
 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('menu') #6
 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/framewo in
 /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Menu.php on
 line 296
```

It's displaying when Session Timeout from Admin

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Ankit Shah  Did you find out what caused it? Same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this issue by linking to an "interstitial" URL first (a controller) which simply redirected to the view URL.

The controller will kick the user back to the login page if the session is expired.  If it's not expired, it will redirect to the view.

Hope this helps.